# Different discount for category products

Tags: price, discount, rules

I want to know is there a way to get different discount for the products in the same category if quantity exceeds a limit.

**For example:**
I have these products with these prices:

- A=10
- B=15
- C=12

And if I choose more than 6 in any combination of these the prices would be:

- A=7
- B=13
- C=11

So if I choose 4xA, 1xB and 1xC the total would be: 52 but if I choose 2xA, 2xB, 2xC the total would be: 62